# C# Trying to set the colour of a string

Tags: c#, string, colors

Just a quick question about setting the colour of the player.playerHealth string, I cant get it to display how i would like. I would like it to be green if its about 50, yellow if its above 20 and red for anything below.

I've tried multiple different solutions and nothing was working so I brought it here.

Im also new to code and this is just a little game for my class.

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void redKeeperBattle()
    {

if (player.playerHealth > 50) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            } else if (player.playerHealth > 20) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            } else {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }

            Console.Clear ();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.WriteLine ("THE RED KEEPER: {0} HP", boss.redKeeperHealth);
            Console.ResetColor ();
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1} HP", player.playerName, player.playerHealth);
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.WriteLine ("");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine ("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine ("1) Attack");
            Console.WriteLine ("2) Dodge");
            Console.ResetColor ();
            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color per line, put your if-else statement before the declaration of your Console.WriteLine:

```
        Console.Clear ();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.WriteLine ("THE RED KEEPER: {0} HP", boss.redKeeperHealth);
        Console.ResetColor ();
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.Write("{0}: ", player.playerName);

//Put your condition here so that the color will reflect:
if (player.playerHealth > 50) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        } else if (player.playerHealth > 20) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        } else {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        }

 Console.Write ("{0} HP", player.playerHealth);
```

Comment: That almost works but it makes the player.playerName the same colour. Im looking for just the player.playerHealth

Comment: Okay, you can check the new code. I used Console.Write instead of Console.WriteLine to seperate the two colors. @JoshuaBohning

Comment: That did it thanks i've been stuck on this for ever :)

Comment: Good to hear that! You can now accept it as an answer for other people's reference as well @JoshuaBohning

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the Foreground colour with the line

```
         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

Hence cut and paste your condition below this line like this,

```
       public static void redKeeperBattle()
{


        Console.Clear ();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

       // Write your condition here like this.
       //The last else condition is not needed as the default colour is mention as red by above line

        if (player.playerHealth > 50) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        } else if (player.playerHealth > 20) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        } 


        Console.WriteLine ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.WriteLine ("THE RED KEEPER: {0} HP", boss.redKeeperHealth);
        Console.ResetColor ();
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1} HP", player.playerName, player.playerHealth);
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.WriteLine ("What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine ("1) Attack");
        Console.WriteLine ("2) Dodge");
        Console.ResetColor ();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

}